# newbie: Rails, swtich to another rails edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rails v2.3 for my project. Then I decided to use **Rails Enterprise Edition**.

So, I installed **Rails Enterprise Edition** in **RVM**.

But after that, how to tell my project to use this new installed Rails enterprise edition?

Comment: Do you mean *Ruby* enterprise edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work woth RVM very simple!

You could see list of all installed ruby versions by typing

```
rvm list
```

To set one of them as current call:

```
rvm use ree
```

If you are using gemsets call this:

```
rvm use mygemset@ree
```

After selecting current ruby version you could again check "rvm list". Near current ruby version there will be arrow.

If you would like to use specific version of ruby in special folder, than put file called ".rvmrc" in that directory (I placed this file in each project root) with content:

```
rvm use mygemset@ree
```

See more info at official RVM site http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/